Wrong position after import the GML/CSV files in QGIS 3 ( which shifted to Africa)
I am newbie to QGIS and following the tutorial from this website to learn how to use QGIS:
https://csdigeolab.gov.hk/en/resources/videos/gis-et-ep2
(Sorry but the video only provides a Chinese version)
I have learnt how to add the XYZ tiles connection of the Hong Kong tomo map and labels.
However, I was facing difficulty when it came to learning how to add GML and CSV data to the map. The data is shifting to Africa instead of Hong Kong.
I have tried to change the project's CRS from WGS84(EPSG:4326) to Hong Kong 1980 Grid system (EPSG:2326) (since it is usual to use EPSG:2326 in HK) and change the data layer to EPSG:2326 as well but nothing has helped.
Screenshot of the data is shifting to Africa:

The GML data I downloaded is from this website:
https://static.csdi.gov.hk/csdi-webpage/download/0d8a2101cfd5560da08d5261b3c6003e/gml
But I think it is unlikely to be the wrong coordinate of the data. Something I did was wrong to cause this issue.
For information, I am using QGIS 3.34.7 LTR.

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This is another example of our most frequent question (QGIS flavor). The difficulty is from telling the software the coordinate reference is what you want it to be, instead of asking it to change the data. Most GIS packages use the coordinate reference definition to render features correctly in the canvas. If you tell the software WGS84 degree data is actually Web Mercator, it will plot the data within 180 meters of the origin of that PCS. You need to Project the data, not Define the projection.

@Vince Thank you for your reply. I have read some websites which teach me how to define the projection instead of projecting the data, like this: link May I ask you to give me the tutorial link to how to project the data or is it a keyword to let me find the instruction to project the data?

99 and 997 thousandths percent of the time, defining the projection is the WRONG thing to do. This is the root of trouble that occurs over and over, in many software platform flavors. Projection metadata is the responsibility of the data provider, not the data consumer. On-the-fly reprojection should handle the rest.

@Vince Sorry but I am being silly and still have no clue how to reproject the layer to the right one. I have even tried to use the 'Reproject Layer' and output it to 'EPSG:2326' from 'EPSG:2326' or 'EPSG:4326' from 'EPSG:2326'. Of course, it has no effect. If nmtoken had not told me he ran it successfully, I would have even suspected the file had a problem.

I'm not sure what you've done wrong but for me the GML is correctly projected (is in urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2326) and displays in the correct location in QGIS >>

Using QGIS 3.34.

May I ask what is the QGIS version you have used? I am kind of feeling frustrated since I spent a day looking for a solution (it seems to be simple by dragging the GML file to QGIS in the videos) but the layer is still located in Africa.

I have read some article like link. It said that the x,y should be swap (but the plugin Swap XY is no longer available) or I should disable the on-the-fly CRS transformation and save the layer as another CRS (the original poster said that he solves the problem by doing so). However, turning off on-the-fly CRS is no longer available in QGIS 3...

I had a try with QGIS 3.37. I opened the OpenSteetmap XYZ layer on the bottom and drag-n-dropped the GML file into the project. No problem at all, the polygons appear in Hong Kong.

Older versions of QGIS may not be correctly reprojecting requiring the axes reordering, EPSG:2326 is Northing/Easting, but later versions get it correct.

I am trying to record all my steps to figure out if I was doing something wrong: Open QGIS 3.34.7 > Current Project CRS is 4326 > Click the bottom-right to open 'Project properties - CRS' dialog > Select HK 1980 Grid System (2326) in the Recently Used CRS > Select OK > Current Project CRS is 2326 > Web > QuickMapServices > OSM > OSM standard > the 'OSM standard' is loaded in the Layers window(Layer CRS:3857) > Right click 'OSM standard' > Layer CRS > Set to 2326 > Find Hong Kong in the map > Download GML file from the website > Right click the GML.zip > Use 7-zip to unzip the file > (next)


(continues) > 'DC_16BC.gml' is extracted in the folder > Drag the 'DC_16BC.gml' to the Layers window in the QGIS > DC_16BC is loaded (Layer CRS is 2326 ) > Cannot find the layer appear on the Hong Kong > Right click DC_16BC > Zoom to Layer(s) > Found the layer appear on the Africa


Right click the DC_16BC > Properties > Information > Screenshot > Properties > Variables > Screenshot

What if you try, open QGIS, change settings > options > CRS and transforms > CRS handling > CRS for Projects > Use CRS from first layer added.  Then drag the gml to QGIS.  Map Canvas should change to EPSG:2326

@nmtoken IT IS WORKS! I don't understand why but it works. How could it be possible? Defining the project CRS manually could not work, though automatically setting the project CRS as the first layer added is working. Is it a bug or something? Pretty fun. This issue was finally fixed. I could continue the tutorial :D Many thanks!
